# http.conf redirect example.com/foo/bar to example.com/foo?id=bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpd.conf

I am trying to create a dynamic page who's contents are determined by a variable passed to it, but I want the url to be nice. Basically I want to have a single index file in the directory /foo that handles any bar. example.com/foo/bar to example.com/foo?id=bar

I have tried everything I can think of in my httpd.conf file. My latest try was:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/foo/([a-z-]*) /foo/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However when I try to load example.com/foo/bar the page that loads is example.com

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: It's still loading example.com/index.php when I visit example.com/foo/bar Maybe one of my other rules is interfering?

```
AllowOverride none
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1.php [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/foo/([a-z-]*)(\/?)$ /foo/index.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

.html to .php, what I'm trying to achieve, and example.com to www.example.com respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/"
    ServerName www.domain.com   
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    <Directory /var/www/>
        #other directives
    </Directory>    
    <Directory /var/www/foo/>   
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
        RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\/?)$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: can you show me your httpd.conf? maybe you have another rule that overwrite this one

Comment: I edited my answer. Do not add the "/" after the "^" in : ^/foo/([a-z-]*)(\/?)$

Comment: you might need to change AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All

Comment: Still no luck. example.com/foo/bar just loads example.com - I am editing the httpd.conf file, not a .htaccess so AllowOverride shouldn't matter. -Tried it anyways, no luck with that either.

Comment: Oh, then use the directory index for the foo path. see my answer